# How to delay a line of code after a button press

Tags: java, android, button, textview, delay

I am new to Java and am trying to delay one line of code after a user presses a button. The line of code incraments an array, *i++*. The reason I would like to do this is because I am animating two textViews by fading them. The one textView fades out while the other fades in and I am trying to change the word being displayed by only incrementing my array index after they have the same Alpha which is half of the animations set duration, 500. I have looked online and I have seen some suggesting a *swing timer* and other suggesting to use *thread.sleep*. Any suggestions? Here is the code for that button :).

```
public void nextWord(View view) { //nextWord is the onclick of the button


        Button nextButton = findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
        Button showTextButton = findViewById(R.id.showTextButton);
        TextView wordTextView = findViewById(R.id.wordTextView);
        EditText editTextView = findViewById(R.id.enterEditText);
        ImageView logoImageView = findViewById(R.id.logoImageView);
        TextView wordTextView1 = findViewById(R.id.wordTextView1);


        i++; // need to delay this


        String displayHint;
        String displayText;

        displayText = enterWord() + chooseArray();
        displayHint = chooseArray();

        wordTextView.setText(displayText);
        editTextView.setHint(displayHint);
        wordTextView1.setText(displayText) ;



        enteredWords[i] = editTextView.getText().toString();

        if (i%2 == 0) {
            ObjectAnimator alphaAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(wordTextView, View.ALPHA, 1f, 0f);
            alphaAnimation.setDuration(1000);
            ObjectAnimator otherAlphaAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(wordTextView1, View.ALPHA, 0f, 1f);
            otherAlphaAnimation.setDuration(1000);

            AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
            animatorSet.playTogether(otherAlphaAnimation,alphaAnimation);
            animatorSet.start();

        } else {
            ObjectAnimator alphaAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(wordTextView, View.ALPHA, 0f, 1f);
            alphaAnimation.setDuration(1000);
            ObjectAnimator otherAlphaAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(wordTextView1, View.ALPHA, 1f, 0f);
            otherAlphaAnimation.setDuration(1000);

            AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
            animatorSet.playTogether(otherAlphaAnimation,alphaAnimation);
            animatorSet.start();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
new Handler().postDelayed(Runnable r, long delay)
```

Use it like

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // fade in new text view
                        }
                    }, 1000);   // time needed for first animation to finish
```

Now, when first animation takes 1000 ms to finish, then second will start after 1000 ms too. You can put it inside `final` value to manipulate those delays at once to keep them synchronized